# How to replicate PHP associative array looping in C++

Tags: c++, loops, multidimensional-array

I have recently started looking into programming C++ and try to understand how to achieve equivalent PHP code in C++.

I'm trying to find a way to create an associative array in C++ and loop it using nested foreach loops or for loops.

An example php code would be:

```
$data = array("type1" = > array( "subtype1" = > array("subsubtype1" = > 10,"subsubtype2" = > 20)),"subtype2" = > array("subsubtype1" = > 30,"subsubtype2" = > 40)));
foreach($data as $type = > $subtypes) {
    foreach($subtypes as $subtype = > $subsubtypes) {
        foreach($subsubtypes as $subsubtype = > $value) {
            $result[$type][$subtype] *= $value;
        }
    }
}
```

So far I have found how to loop multidimensional arrays using for loops [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g4rnIvyT--w), however I can't find information about looping associative arrays and storing results to associative arrays in C++.

My question would be is it possible to do the same thing in C++ and how?

Comment: For an associative array, `std::unordered_map<Key, Value>`??

Comment: [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) (or [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)) and [range-for loops](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) (or some [standard algorithm function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm))?

Comment: In this specific case the innermost loop could possibly be a call to [`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) with a [lambda](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).